# How to set application as service which can start at the boot of the system in installer it self

Tags: windows-installer, system, boot, jpackage

I am creating an installer for Mac and Windows using the commands:

```
jpackage --name Test --input . --main-jar test.jar --type msi --mac-package-identifier com.test.Main

jpackage --name Test --input . --main-jar test.jar --type pkg --mac-package-identifier com.test.Main
```

I want to install an application that runs automatically on system startup, so the user does not have to open it every time, like Google Drive, Docker, and Dropbox do.

Comment: Do you really want a Windows service, or do you just want an app that launches at login?  To do that, you have to have an installer application that creates the registry entries that are needed to have a startup app.

Comment: I want an app that launches at login in the system.

Comment: If the application shall start at Windows boot time, register it as a service. If the applicaton shall start when the user logs in, install it normally plus add a menu entry in the Autostart group.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to provide a post-image script. That is a script which will be invoked after your application installer has run. The default script does nothing. See [how to override JPackage resources](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/jpackage/override-jpackage-resources.html#GUID-1B718F8B-B68D-4D46-B1DB-003D7729AAB6).

Your custom script can add the application to the registry so it gets treated as a service, or add it to the (global/user's) Autostart group.